# redirect no slash to slash with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect all links whitout slash to trailing slash, this is my htaccess and always opens the page whit or whitout, i need just open the page whit slash.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?artist=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?artist=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right under the `RewriteEngine On`, add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi, thats code redirects http://mydomain.com/post/search-google/ to http://mydomain.com/search-google/

Comment: My htaccess is located in:  mydomain.com/post/

Comment: @josekaizer then you need to change `/$1/` to `/post/$1/`, or add a `RewriteBase /post/` and remove the leading slash: `$1/`